# UV unwrapping is incorrect?

Tags: texturing, uv

I UV unwrapped this wood texture onto the handle, and rotated it in the UV editor to make the grain vertical. Can anyone tell me why in the world 3/4 of the handle rotated properly but that single strip down the left side remained horizontal? I UV Unwrapped the entire handle so I'm confused... Thank you! [image]

Comment: I guess because Blender decided to rotate it this way, you just have to select this face in the 3D view, then rotate it 90° in the UVImage Editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender decided to rotate it this way, you just have to select this face in the 3D view, then rotate it 90° in the UVImage Editor.